# How to resize an ImageView by pressing a MenuItem

Tags: android, exception, resize, imageview, try-catch

I am trying to create an ImageView that is resized when the user presses a MenuItem. I tried to use the following code, but I get an error and my application stops.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.sub_item_25_percent:
            try
            {
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(imageView1.getLayoutParams());
            params.width = Pages.PAGE_WIDTH_25_PERCENT;
            params.height = Pages.PAGE_HEIGHT_25_PERCENT;

            imageView1.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
            break;
     }
```

}

As you can see, I already used a try-catch-block to get informations about the exception, but the application is still just stopping without displaying the Toast.

Does anyone have a clue what I could do to fix my problem?

Comment: Debug your app and then paste the stack trace from LogCat. That will have all the information on what caused the force close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)  
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.sub_item_25_percent:

            imageView1.getLayoutParams().width = Pages.PAGE_WIDTH_25_PERCENT;
            imageView1.getLayoutParams().height = Pages.PAGE_HEIGHT_25_PERCENT;

            imageView1.requestLayout();

        break;
     }
```

}